# Exact reflective subcategories of abelian categories are abelian.

Tags: abelian-categories

In this question reflective subcategories means full reflective replete subcategories for short.
I understand that reflective subcategories inherits good behavior of (co)limit. For example reflective subcategories of complete/cocomplete/preabelian categories have the same property.

My question is how to prove that an exact reflective subcategory (which means the reflector is exact) of an abelian category is again abelian? I’m not sure which criterion for abelianness gives a neater proof. Am I supposed to show every monic/epic is a kernel/cokernel or every morphism is strict?

I saw this claim in the last paragraph of the following note, where the author uses it to prove the category of sheaves is abelian by showing the sheafification functor is exact.
[https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~bahra004/alg-geo/sheafification.pdf](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Ebahra004/alg-geo/sheafification.pdf)

Comment: Does it has anything to do with “localization of abelian categories is abelian” or relationship between reflection and localization?